# How to generate nosetter.camelcase-underscore access strategy with NHibernate mapping by code?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Cant find appropriate accessor. Should it be just NoSetter or Field?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **have** a (read-only) property, you should use `Accessor.NoSetter`

The specific naming convention is determined automatically by NHibernate (of course, try not to have both `_myProp`, `_MyProp` and `myProp` fields, as NH will just pick the first one IIRC)